# Duplicate items in the recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am new here, I have an activity that contains `ViewPager` with two `Fragments`. Each `Fragment` has a `RecyclerView`.  on selecting a tab through `OnTabSelection` items in the `RecyclerView` gets repeated. I can't understand what is causing this problem.

I am using `DataHandler` to save the data because I have to use this data in other activities as well.

```
class DataHandler {

    private ArrayList<MenuHolder> listOfItemsFromJson;
    private static DataHandler mInstance = null;

    static public DataHandler getInstance() {
        if (null == mInstance) {
            mInstance = new DataHandler();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public DataHandler() {
        listOfItemsFromJson = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<MenuHolder> getListOfItemsFromJson() {
        return listOfItemsFromJson;
    }
    public void clearList() {
        listOfItemsFromJson.clear();
    }
    public void addData(MenuHolder holder) {
        listOfItemsFromJson.add(holder);
    }
    public MenuHolder getData(int position) {
        return listOfItemsFromJson.get(position);

    }
    public void removeData(int position) {
        listOfItemsFromJson.remove(getData(position));
    }
    public int size() {
        return listOfItemsFromJson.size();
    }
}
```

Here is my `Fragment`

```
class ComboRecycler extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayout mViewCartLayout;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recylerViewLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_combo, container, false);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recylerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recylerViewLayoutManager);
        new FetchTask().execute();
        return view;
    }


    public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONArray jsonArray;
               ........

    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            if (result != null) {
                try {


                    for (int i = 0; i < DataHandler.getInstance().size(); i++) {

                        if (DataHandler.getInstance().getData(i).isCombo()) {
                            DataHandler.getInstance().removeData(i);

                        }

                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject mJsonObject = result
                                .getJSONObject(i);

                        MenuHolder mDataHolder = new MenuHolder();
                         ......
                        mDataHolder.setCombo(true);
                        mDataHolder.setItemCount("0");
                        DataHandler.getInstance().addData(mDataHolder);
                    }

                    setAdapter();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setAdapter() {
        index.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < DataHandler.getInstance().size(); i++) {
            if (DataHandler.getInstance().getListOfItemsFromJson().get(i).isCombo()) {
                index.add(i);
            }
        }
        recyclerComboAdapter = new RecyclerComboAdapter(getActivity(), index);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerComboAdapter);
    }

}
```

Here is my `RecyclerAdapter`

```
class RecyclerComboAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerComboAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    View view1;
    ViewHolder viewHolder1;
    ArrayList<Integer> index;
    LinearLayout mViewCart;
    Recycler recycler;
    private AQuery mQuery;

    public RecyclerComboAdapter(Context context1, ArrayList<Integer> index) {

        this.index = index;
        context = context1;
        mQuery = new AQuery(context1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.combo_meals_adapter, parent, false);

        viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);

        return viewHolder1;


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final int pos = position;
        MenuHolder menuHolder =DataHandler.getInstance().getData(index.get(position));

        holder.itemName.setText(menuHolder.getItemname());
        holder.itemPrice.setText(menuHolder.getItemprice());
        mQuery.id(holder.imageView).image(menuHolder.getItemPicture());
        holder.counter.setText(menuHolder.getItemCount());


      }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return index.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;

        TextView add, minus, plus, counter, itemName, itemPrice;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemnametxt);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            itemPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
            minus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.minus);
            plus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
            counter = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
            add = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.addtxt);
        }
    }
}
```

After swiping the list multiple times I am seeing repeated list items. Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your routine to delete items looks fishy, you are modifying your list while iterating it, so you are most likely skipping to delete some items but keep adding more and more